# Binding selected items to dynamically set list

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a window that displays a `ListBox` that is binded to `ListOfPlayers` (a list of strings).

The purpose of this window is to select players from `ListOfPlayers` to form a team.

Sometimes, I want to select players for the red team and I have a `ListOfRedPlayers` (a `ObservableCollection<string>` property).

Sometimes, I want to select players for the blue team and I have a corresponding `ListOfBluePlayers`.

Right now, in my window constructor, I have a `bool isRedTeam` parameter and based on that parameter I populate the  `ListOfRedPlayers` or `ListOfBluePlayers`.

That works, but it sucks because it doesn't scale neatly beyond 2 teams. I could use an Enum (RedTeam, BlueTeam, GreenTeam, etc.) but that doesn't seem so neat as well.

I tried passing the corresponding list of players property by reference, but I can't do that (can't pass property by reference).

Note that I do use the property setters (e.g. `ListOfBluePlayers = new ObservableCollection<string>();` as opposed to just `ListOfBluePlayers.Clear()`) so directly using the input parameter `ListOfPlayers` wouldn't work.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: An enumeration would be fine. If you want it to be infinitely scaleable you can just use a name string for the team, but there are other problems with your architecture for doing that. You'd be better off creating a Team class that maintains its own list of players as well as metadata about the team such as the team name. Then you have one List< Team > to maintain rather than separate lists for each team, and the Player can hold a reference to the Team it is a part of.

Comment: hi take a josh suggestion I try to give you an other way. you can create an observablecollection<Team> and you can binding directly to it, and set the displayedName property at a property "name" of Team class.
So you can choose from a name of team and select the whole Team class

Comment: Maybe use Team #1, Team #2, etc.  Indices are easier to work with than colours.

Answer (score 4):

Will this help in the task?

```
bool isRedTeam = true; // true/false

ObservableCollection<string> ListOfRedPlayers { get; set; }
ObservableCollection<string> ListOfBluePlayers { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<string> ListOfPlayers
{
    get
    {
        if(isRedTeam) return ListOfRedPlayers
        else return ListOfBluePlayers
    }
    set
    {
        if (isRedTeam) ListOfRedPlayers = value;
        else ListOfBluePlayers = value;
    }
}
```